# How do I create a new object from an array which holds different objects in c++

Tags: c++

I have a base class "A" and many derived classes, say "B", "C", "D".
I need to have an array which holds these objects (or pointers).  I have a function which will take an index into this array and should create one of the objects (make new object) in the array. How do I do this ? Following is a snippet, showing just wrappers below.

```
class A 
{
};

class B: public A
{
};

class C: public A{
};

class D: public A{
};

static A anArray[] = {B, C,D };



int main() {
    `A anObject = myFunction(2);`
}
```

In the above code, when I call myFunction, I should be able to get a new `D`

Comment: use `dynamic_cast`. btw - you cannot store `B or C...` in your array. Your array must be of a type `A&` or `A*`

Comment: How about a virtual `clone` function? Of course, that requires you to have an array of references or pointers. And that `anObject` is a pointer.

Comment: @Fureeish Definitely not! Usage of `dynamic_cast` is a serious indicator of a design flaw. I'd recommend using something like `std::vector<unique_ptr<A>>` instead.

Comment: Nothing here even requires a `clone` function. Base class pointers with implicit casts should take care of it all. Did you even try before asking?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achive this,

here's one way:

```
#include <memory>

class A { 
    public:
    virtual ~A() = default;   // important
    };

class B: public A { };

class C: public A{ };

class D: public A{ };

static std::unique_ptr<A> anArray[] = { 
    std::make_unique<B>(), 
    std::make_unique<C>(), 
    std::make_unique<D>()
    };
```

Comment: Better use a `std::vector` or `std::array` to wrap that raw array.

Comment: @user0042 I guess that depends on whether he ever means to extend it or remove items.

If we're going to get into data structures like vector, then there are some nice alternatives in boost, depending on requirements.